# Change an image without refresh whole page

Tags: html

I have an image control in a div. Under this image I am showing a button to change the image. On change image I am replacing the last image with a new image in image folder. So for previous image and new image path will be same.

So now how to show new image without refresh that page.

Comment: You can use JavaScript? Have you tried anything?

Comment: jQuery all the way. This is really simple but we need more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you changing the Image in the folder.

on button click event you can do this.

You can force the browser to reload the image by passing an extra variable like so:

```
 clickfunction()
 {
 d = new Date();
 $("#myimg").attr("src", "/myimg.jpg?"+d.getTime());
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do AJAX call to change the Image path, getting from server and then changed image will show without refreshing the whole page.

Note: It will be better if you add a version to the new image URL, so that your image will not be cached.

Comment: yes Your point is right. Please tell me how to add version in image url

Comment: @kuldeep did you try my answer?

Answer (score -1):

If you do not care about the loading time of your page you could also
load all other img in a div within the same page, but don't display them - replace with js...
(easier to use / slower page / not very dynamic... => In general some ajax magic is better suited)